# ¿Cómo asignar fecha a un DateTimePicker solo cuando se escoge la fecha?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, vba, datetime

Buenas tardes compañeros del foro.
Estoy diseñando un formuario en VB.NET que tiene 2 DateTimePicker los cuales uno de ellos se carga en blanco mediante el siguiente codigo: `DtpFechaNacimiento.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom DtpFechaNacimiento.CustomFormat = "''"`

Lo que quiero conseguir es que al momento de darle Click al control de fecha no me asigne fecha sino hasta que le de click en el día que escoja.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Formulario con datetimepicker vacio]

Como se puede observar mi formulario carga los DatetimePicker sin fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero evitar que con solo darle click al DatetimePicker me cargue la fecha por defecto. NO quiero que haga eso, solo quiero que cuando yo escoja la fecha ahí si me coloque la fecha en el datetimepicker.

Espara evitar que si un usuario solo da click al datetimepicker y no escoge la fecha de su preferencia no me coloque fechas por defecto.

Comment: Comparte el código de esos DT picker por favor.

Comment: Antes de ver temas de código, hay que hacer una análisis funcional del formulario. No sé si has tenido en cuenta una cosa. Al dar click al DateTimerPicker, se genera un evento y muestra el calendario. En ese momento se entiende que el usuario quiere seleccionar fecha (ha hecho click), por lo que el objeto coloca la fecha "ahora" por defecto. En ese caso, ¿por qué motivo no es correcta la selección de la fecha actual si en verdad el usuario ha hecho click en la caja del campo fecha?  De haber alguna restrición, se podría jugar con la propiedad MaximumDateTime y MinimumDateTime

Comment: Perdón, no me fijé que es un campo de fecha de nacimiento. No tengas en cuenta el comentario de arriba

Comment: No sé en qué lenguaje estás trabajando, ya que indicas c# y vba. De cualquier modo, entiendo que no quieres que el campo adquiera valores con la fecha del "ahora", ya que es una fecha de nacimiento.  Por mi experiencia, es bastante problemático, ya que los usuarios tienden que tomar atajos y muchos no se fijarán, aun seleccionando el dia/mes correcto, que están seleccionando una fecha del año actual. Te propongo dos soluciones:
A la hora de validar el formulario, controla que la fecha asignada no sea del año actual. En Vba: Year(campofecha ) <> Year(now)

Comment: Y la otra solución. Dividir el campo de fecha de nacimiento en tres campos: día, mes y año. Con ello consigues que el usuario se fije en detalle en el año...(ese es el motivo, entre otros, por lo que en muchas webs se usa ese metodo de tres campos...

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.
He conseguido una manera para que el control de fecha no asigne fecha por defecto a travez del siguuiente codigo:

```
Private Sub DtpFechaNacimiento_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DtpFechaNacimiento.ValueChanged
    Dim FechaAnual As Integer = FechaHoy.Year
    Dim Edad = FechaAnual - DtpFechaNacimiento.Value.Year
    If DtpFechaNacimiento.Checked = False Then
        Me.DtpFechaNacimiento.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
        Me.DtpFechaNacimiento.Value = DtpFechaNacimiento.Value
       
    End If
End Sub
```

Para evitar que el control te asigne fecha solo con dar click se debe colocar en el evento `Changed` que el Datetimepicker.value sea igual Datetimepicker.value
Al estar en el evento Changed no asignará fecha sino hasta que el control detecte un cambio o hasta que el mismo usuario escoja la fecha.